# Mouse Touchpad Stops Intermittently Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mouse

My touchpad stops working when the computer comes out of "suspend".
It usually takes exactly 3 reboots to make it start working again.

External mice do not have this problem.

How do I tell if this is a software or hardware issue?

The computer is a Toshiba satellite m300.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Try in a terminal `sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps`

Comment: Neither of these worked. The problem has changed and now the mouse just intermittently stops working and starts again after a few seconds. I suspect it's hardware related but don't know how to prove this.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but it happens all the time, not just when I come out of suspend. It seems to be some kind of USB problem as my scanner stops in the middle of scans sometimes as well. Anyone out there have any ideas?